# Does the code after the return statement in configurable.js ever get run?

Tags: magento-1.9, price

In `js/varien/configurable.js`, `Product.config.prototype` has this method that changes the displayed price of a configurable item based on the option selected from the dropdown menu:

```
reloadPrice: function(){
        if (this.config.disablePriceReload) {
            return;
        }
        var price    = 0;
        var oldPrice = 0;
        for(var i=this.settings.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            var selected = this.settings[i].options[this.settings[i].selectedIndex];
            if(selected.config){
                price    += parseFloat(selected.config.price);
                oldPrice += parseFloat(selected.config.oldPrice);
            }
        }

        optionsPrice.changePrice('config', {'price': price, 'oldPrice': oldPrice});
        optionsPrice.reload();

        return price;

        if($('product-price-'+this.config.productId)){
            $('product-price-'+this.config.productId).innerHTML = price;
        }
        this.reloadOldPrice();
    }
```

What I don't understand here is, why include the if statement and the call to reloadOldPrice() after the return? It seems like this code should never be run, so what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code after a return will NEVER run. Seems like someone forgot to clean up their code!

Comment: You're probably right! I'm just checking my sanity on that one. Thanks!